# How can I create Apple ID for a child without a Credit Card?

Tags: itunes, icloud, iphone, apple-id

I am trying to create an Apple ID for my 10-year-old son. However, I do not have a Credit Card, only a Debit Card. I'm using the iCloud 'Family' setting, but it says 'Credit Card Required'. I guess this is because, legally, someone under 18 may have a Debit Card, but you must be 18 to have a Credit Card. How can I bypass this? I'm using an iPhone 4S, running the latest iOS update (I updated today). What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sign out.
2. Search for any free app.
3. Select "Get" and "Install App".
4. You should see screen, that you need to log in to download. Select "Create New Apple ID".
5. You should see "None" option when selecting payment method.
6. Activate Apple ID and you have created new Apple ID for your son.

Then just sign out from son's Apple ID and log in to yours.